# Coverting insert query to a prepared statment

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

i've been struggling with this insert query as it doesn't work and doesn't give any errors, yet similar queries work just fine with other tables only this one doesn't work
I've been trying to convert it to a pdo prepared statement but i can't do it if anyone could help with this conversion would be really helpful

```
//med_en_name

 $med_en_name = $_POST["med_en_name"];

            //med_ar_name

 $med_ar_name = $_POST["med_ar_name"];

            //lat_name

 $lat_name = $_POST["lat_name"];

            //che_name

 $che_name = $_POST["che_name"];

            //med_desc

 $med_desc = $_POST["med_desc"];

                //med_note

 $med_note = $_POST["med_note"];

                //act_mat

 $act_mat = $_POST["act_mat"];

                //rea_use

 $rea_use = $_POST["rea_use"];

                //side_eff

 $side_eff = $_POST["side_eff"];

                //contraind

 $contraind = $_POST["contraind"];

                //price_wz_dis

 $price_wz_dis = $_POST["price_wz_dis"];

                //price_wzo_dis

 $price_wzo_dis = $_POST["price_wzo_dis"];

                //quan_for_prod

 $quan_for_prod = $_POST["quan_for_prod"];

                //pack_for_prod

 $pack_for_prod = $_POST["pack_for_prod"];

                //med_class

 $med_class = $_POST["med_class"];

                //med_store

 $med_store = $_POST["med_store"];

                //med_type

 $med_type = $_POST["med_type"];

                //med_comp

 $med_comp = $_POST["med_comp"];

                //med_chk

 $med_chk = $_POST["med_chk"];

                //med_start_date

$med_start_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['med_start_date']));

                //med_end_date

 $med_end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["med_end_date"]));

                //med_rec_date

 $med_rec_date =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["med_rec_date"]));

                //med_flag

 $med_flag = $_POST["med_flag"];

if(!empty($_FILES['upload_Product']['name'] ))
 {

 $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg","JPG","PNG","GIF","BMP","mp3","MP3","mp4","MP4","3gp","3GP");
 $uploaddir = "uploads/"; //image upload directory

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['upload_Product']['name']);
        $size=filesize($_FILES['upload_Product']['tmp_name']);
        //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
          $ext = getExtension($filename);
          $ext = strtolower($ext);
         if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
         {
           if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
             {
           $image_name=time().$filename;
           $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name;
              if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_Product']['tmp_name'], $newname))
              {

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `id14270028_it_pharma`.`pha_medicine` (`M_ID`, `MedicineName`, `LatinName`, `ChemicalName`, `Type_ID`, `ActiveMaterial`, `Medicine_MD_ID`, `store_id`, `ReasonForUsing`, `SideEffects`, `MedicinePhoto`, `Contraindications`, `PacketsNum`, `Description`, `Notes`, `PriceWZdiscount`, `PriceWZOUTdiscount`, `AllPacketswzQTY`, `Company_ID`, `medicine_flag`, `created_by`, `creation_date`, `prod_start_date`, `prod_end_date`, `prod_rec_date`, `ArabicName`, `ChkDrugsTable`) VALUES (NULL, '".$med_en_name."', '".$lat_name."', '".$che_name."', '$med_type', '".$act_mat."', '$med_class',  '$med_store','".$rea_use."', '".$side_eff."','".$image_name."','".$contraind."', '$quan_for_prod', '".$med_desc."', '".$med_note."', '$price_wz_dis', '$price_wzo_dis', '$pack_for_prod', '".$med_comp."', '".$med_flag."', '$user_id', '$current_date', '".$med_start_date."', '".$med_end_date."', '".$med_rec_date."', '".$med_ar_name."', '".$med_chk."');");


              }


            else

             {

                     echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit! so moving unsuccessful! </span>';
             }
              }
              else
              {
            echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit!</span>';
              }
          }
          else
         {
             echo '<span class="imgList">Unknown extension!</span>';
         }
        }

 else
 {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `id14270028_it_pharma`.`pha_medicine` (`M_ID`, `MedicineName`, `LatinName`, `ChemicalName`, `Type_ID`, `ActiveMaterial`, `Medicine_MD_ID`, `store_id`, `ReasonForUsing`, `SideEffects`, `MedicinePhoto`, `Contraindications`, `PacketsNum`, `Description`, `Notes`, `PriceWZdiscount`, `PriceWZOUTdiscount`, `AllPacketswzQTY`, `Company_ID`, `medicine_flag`, `created_by`, `creation_date`, `prod_start_date`, `prod_end_date`, `prod_rec_date`, `ArabicName`, `ChkDrugsTable`) VALUES (NULL, '".$med_en_name."', '".$lat_name."', '".$che_name."', '$med_type', '".$act_mat."', '$med_class',  '$med_store','".$rea_use."', '".$side_eff."','0','".$contraind."', '$quan_for_prod', '".$med_desc."', '".$med_note."', '$price_wz_dis', '$price_wzo_dis', '$pack_for_prod', '".$med_comp."', '".$med_flag."', '$user_id', '$current_date', '".$med_start_date."', '".$med_end_date."', '".$med_rec_date."', '".$med_ar_name."', '".$med_chk."');");
 }
```

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Tip: If you name your placeholders properly you can just `execute($_POST)`. This means you don't need to declare umpteen different variables.

Comment: Well, you are not checking for mysql errors at all, so no wonder that you are not getting any errors...

Comment: It's worth noting this code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection bugs so if this is on a public server this is exposing you to extraordinary levels of risk.

Comment: @tadman yes, I'm new to php and doing this application for a college project, so i get a lot of problems yet, this one i couldn't solve it myself, I'll look into your provided links, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The rough approach for PDO is to replace all your `$` variables in the string with a `:` named placeholder and remove any quotes as those aren't necessary, the statement binding takes care of that for you. For example:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `pha_medicine` (`MedicineName`, ...) VALUES (:med_en_name, ...)");
```

Where it's worth noting that instead of listing `M_ID` as a column with a `NULL` value, just skip that column. Likewise, omit the `;` statement delimiter when doing SQL in code. That's only necessary in interactive SQL shells.

Once prepared you can execute with variables like:

```
$sth->execute($_POST);
```

If you've taken the time to ensure that your placeholder names match the variables in `$_POST` exactly.